# Schengen visa lost

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, study, schengen-visas, lost-documents

I found exact similar questions but no specific answers and I am still struck.

I am in France on a student exchange until November 2016. My Indian passport with Schengen visa was stolen. I got a duplicate passport from Indian embassy in Paris without a Schengen visa.

How can I get my Schengen visa reissued in France? I have even emailed the French Consulate in Pondicherry but was asked to contact the prefecture here in France. The prefecture said that I have to apply for a residence permit by paying 340 Euros.

Anybody who has the first-hand experience can shed light on it?

Comment: "up to September 2016" - so you're supposed to leave in two weeks?

Comment: Till November...

Comment: Not a solution or full explanation but €340 is what's called “*frais de visa de régularisation*”, which is a kind of penalty people have to pay when they apply for a first residence permit after a period of illegal stay. This assumes of course that you have some strong claim to a residence permit (e.g. family permit), otherwise you would just attract a refusal (and an injunction to leave France to boot), which would not help you at all.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that you can successfully do that for a student permit if you are considered to be in France illegally. So I have no idea whether it's really a good idea to apply for such a residence permit. And it's not obvious to me either that you are actually illegally in France (a visa was issued to you and there must be a record of it) so maybe you should not admit as much or have to pay this penalty.

Comment: One option, if you only want to stay until November is to stay put and simply leave then. You're not very likely to run into trouble until then and I *think* than in France you are extremely unlikely to receive a ban and would generally not even get a fine (other Schengen countries like Germany are harsher). You might get a black mark on your record that would make obtaining a Schengen visa more difficult in the immediate future but I am not even sure of that. Do check this with a lawyer or support group however because if I am wrong the consequences could be very severe.

Comment: Have you tried asking this question in the Indian embassy in Paris?

Comment: Yes, I have contacted the Indian Embassy at Paris, they said me to contact the French Authorities not even mentioning clearly what that means.